# Two words separated by a space followed by a comma more than one time

Tags: regex

I want to create a Regex that separates any number of words by semi-colons. For example:

```
word1 word2;word3 word4;word5 word6....
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
^.*(;){0,}
```

But this allows using more than one semi-colon side by side.

Comment: There are no commas in your example. Did you mean a semicolon?

Comment: Do you mean you want to extract those words (`[^;]+`) or validate a string consisting of these words (`^\w+(?:;\w+)*$`)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it's work fine how to change regex to match somthing like that word1 word2;word3 word4; word5 word6;....

Comment: Actually, it is not clear what you need. If whitespace separated pairs of words that are semi-colon separated, you may use `^\w+\s+\w+(?:;\s*\w+\s+\w+)*$`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comment, you need an expression that matches a string of words separated by either a semicolon, a space, or both.

`^(\w+( ;?|; ?))+\w+$`

Explanation:

```
^           | Enforce beginning of string
(           | Group the following:
  \w+       |   One or more consecutive word characters
  ( ;?|; ?) |   A space, semicolon, or combination of the two
)+          | End group; match one or more of them
\w+         | One or more consecutive word characters
$           | Enforce end of string
```

#### [Try it here](https://regex101.com/r/itmbQF/5)

Comment: This will also match [spaces and semi-colons at the end of the string](https://regex101.com/r/itmbQF/4).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew OP never specified that that isn't allowed.

Comment: Right, no idea what OP needs. In most cases, people do not want to match trailing whitespace/punctuation, hence my comment.

Comment: But that does make more sense. Improved my answer.